# MacBook not charging

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a 2008 Black MacBook. The battery indicator says 'Not Charging' and if I remove the power adapter it powers off instantly.

I had OS X installed, installed Windows (Not bootcamp, Windows only) and then reistalled 10.6.8. Since reinstalling OS X the battery has never charged.

The battery only has 68 charge cycles on it, so it seems strange it would have already died.

Comment: Please first try an [SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) and report back.

Comment: How long was the charger in for? This can happen when the battery has completely run out, and you go to charge again. This can also be a logic board issue. Lets see what an SMC reset and a longer charge period do first.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, SMC reset should be your first port of call.

If that doesn't change anything, try removing the battery and see if the system recognises the change. (Status should change to "no battery"/battery icon with an x). If it changes, that pretty much means that the battery is toast.

I'm guessing that your battery has failed as this is the most likely cause of these symptoms. Cycle counts aren't a sure fire way of determining battery health, they can just die.

If your battery is less than 12 months old, you are entitled to a replacement from Apple.

Comment: I've had the exact same problem with a 2010 MBP after it was in storage for several months, and an SMC reset did indeed do the trick.